# reference and value types c#

Tags: c#, memory-management

I am learning C# memory management and faced weird to me thing.
I dynamically allocate memory for Student object and change it in a method — it is being changed.
I dynamically allocate memory for int object and change it in a method — it isn't being changed.
Why??

```
class Student
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student s1 = new Student();            
        s1.id = 5;
        s1.name = "myname";

        ChangeStud(s1);

        Console.WriteLine(s1.id);
        Console.WriteLine(s1.name);

        int x = new int();
        x = 2;
        ChangeInt(x);

        Console.WriteLine(x);

    }

    static void ChangeStud(Student s)
    {
        s.id = 500;
        s.name = "changedname";
    }

    static void ChangeInt(int x)
    {
        x = 500;
    }
}
```

The output is:

500
changedname
2

Comment: Because you're saying `2 = 100` in the `ChangeInt` method. It's not changing the value of `x` at all. `x` represents a number, not an object.

Comment: use out or ref parameters if that needs to be changed.

Comment: I suggest googling "C# reference vs value type" and reading the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a class object by value is similar to passing a pointer to a data structure in a non-object-oriented language, because what is actually passed is the memory location of the object.  Since that address is given, the memory to which the address refers can be modified.

Passing a scalar variable value such as an integer is just passing a value.  The called method doesn't receive the memory location of the int, just a copy of the value.  Any changes will not modify the value in the original memory location.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are changing the int in the ChangeInt method but the  parameter is copied not referenced you can either use the ref keyword or return the value of the method:

```
static void ChangeInt(ref int x)
{
    x = 500;
}
```

or

```
static int ChangeInt(int x)
{
    return 500;
}
```

If you use the later method remember to catch the value